# How to print integers in typing order in C - increasing, decreasing or evenly

Tags: c, printing, integer, typing

I have a problem with a c program I'm trying to write. The program must store integers in array (read from the keyboard). The numbers must be printed out in the order of entering, for example if you enter: 3 2 0 5 5 5 8 9, the ouput should be:

3 2 0 - decreasing
5 5 5 - evenly
8 9 - increasing

The problem for me is, that I can't write an algorithm which to be able to work in all cases.
I was trying to "flag" the elements with another array(using the same index, to save for each integer a value 1-for increasing, -1-for decreasing and 0 for evenly), but this works partly.
Have you any other ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

    int array[100];
    int flag[100];
    int num, i;

    printf("Enter how many numbers you want to type: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        if((array[i]<array[i+1])) {
            flag[i]=flag[i+1]=1;
        }
        if(array[i]>array[i+1]) {
            flag[i]=flag[i+1]=-1;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        if(array[i]==array[i+1]) {
            flag[i]=flag[i+1]=0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf("%d ",flag[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        if(flag[i]==1) {
            do{
                if(flag[i]==1){
                    printf("%d ",array[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }while(flag[i]==1);
            printf(" - increasing\n");
        }

        if(flag[i]==0) {
            do{
                if(flag[i]==0){
                    printf("%d ",array[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }while(flag[i]==0);
            printf(" - evenly\n");
        }

        if(flag[i]==-1) {
            do{
                if(flag[i]==-1) {
                    printf("%d ",array[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }while(flag[i]==-1);
            printf(" - decreasing\n");
        }

    } 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a few more examples? What do you want if user enters `4 2 5 8 0 9 1 6 6`?

Comment: yeah, and should be divided in the order of typing by the user

Comment: 4 2 - decreasing
5 8 - increasing
0 9 - increasing
1 6 - increasing
6 - I dont know,

Comment: 4 3 1 0 -3 -3 -3 5 6 7 3 3


4 3 1 0 - decrease   -3 -3 -3 – evenly   5 6 7 – increase   3 3 - evenly

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

- You only know if the 'first' number belongs to a descending, even, or ascending sequence after you see the 'second' number.
- The 'third' number either belongs to the same sequence as the first two or is the 'first' number of another sequence.

So: check two numbers and assign a sequence type.
Keep checking numbers in the same sequence.
When you cannot assign the same sequence go back to checking two numbers and assigning a sequence.

Something like

```
int *n1, *n2, *n3;
n1 = <first element>;
n2 = n1 + 1;
n3 = n2 + 1;

/* some kind of loop */
if ((n3 - n2) HAS_SOME_SIGN_AS (n2 - n1)) /* n3 belongs to the sequence */;
n1++;
n2++;
n3++;
/* end loop */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int status(a, b){
    if(a < b) return 1;
    if(a > b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int array[100]={0};
    int old_status, new_status;
    int old_pos;
    int num, i, j;
    const char* status_message[] = {"decreasing","evenly","increasing", "i don't know"};

    printf("Enter how many numbers you want to type: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);

    //{num | 1 < num <= 100}
    old_status =status(array[0], array[1]);
    old_pos = 0;
    for(i=1;i<num;++i){
        new_status = status(array[i-1], array[i]);
        if(old_status != new_status){
            for(j=old_pos;j<i;++j)
                printf("%d ", array[j]);
            printf("- %s\n", status_message[1 + old_status]);
            old_status = (i<num-1)? status(array[i], array[i+1]):2;
            old_pos = i;
        }
    }
    if(old_pos < num){ //not output section output
        for(j=old_pos;j<i;++j)
            printf("%d ", array[j]);
        printf("- %s\n", status_message[1 + old_status]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```